# Replacing the Windows Phone Operating System?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, custom-rom

I looked into updating an old Windows Phone to run a different ROM like Windows 10 but couldn't find much on the web. I have 2 Windows Phones so I thought I'd tinker with one of them to see if I can get any cool features.

Does anyone have any good links to ROM sites/guides for Windows Phones?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: @RowlandShaw A Lumia 630.